# Latex: How to add email and address as in documentclass article

Tags: affiliation, authblk, addresses, email

I want the output become like this below the title

[image]

I did this command to get that output.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[blocks]{authblk}
\renewcommand{\Authsep}{, }
\renewcommand{\Authand}{, }
\renewcommand{\Authands}{, }
\setlength{\affilsep}{0cm}
\renewcommand\Authfont{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\Affilfont{\normalfont\small}


\author[1]{Penulis Pertama}
\author[2]{Penulis Kedua}
\author[3]{Penulis Ketiga}
\author[4]{Penulis Keempat}


\makeatletter
\renewcommand\AB@affilsepx{, \protect\Affilfont}    
\affil[1]{penulispertama@universitasbumigora.ac.id}
\affil[2]{penuliskedua@universitasbumigora.ac.id}
\affil[3]{penuliskeempat@universitasbumigora.ac.id}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\AB@affilsepx{\\\vspace{0.5cm} \protect\Affilfont}
\makeatother
\affil[4]{penuliskeempat@universitasbumigora.ac.id}

\affil[1,2,3,4]{Universitas Bumigora, Indonesia}
```

I need help to correct me about the affil. I make the last email separate to the other one in that command. I thought it's not the good way.

Comment: When I compile [this code](https://pastebin.com/raw/HxwtVbWS) I obtain [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovHVi.png) which seems to be exactly what you're after... except for the emails being on separate lines, but that's because the text block is not wide enough to accommodate two on one line. So I don't see what you're problem is here. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Werner I mean, my problem is the command of email is separate .. the last email is after `\makeatletter
\renewcommand\AB@affilsepx{\\\vspace{0.5cm} \protect\Affilfont}
\makeatother` .. Can I obtain the output without separate the email in the command ?

Comment: Sure... but it seems like you just want the code to look nice. You'll run into similar problems where you might not like the way the code looks, but it provides the output you want. How about [this code](https://pastebin.com/raw/z2JN3yVR) as an alternative to you [`authblk`](//ctan.org/pkg/authblk) option?

Comment: @Werner yeah right, I want the code look nice to .. :D thank you for your answer .. it's works and has better look ..